# PHP eval a string as a class

Tags: php

I'm retreiving a string and I would like to call it as a new class

I've tried : $class = eval("new $string()") but it's not working.

```
$class = eval("new {$string}()");
```

Comment: `eval("\$class = new {$string}()");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need eval for that.

```
$class = new $string();
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted ? It actually answers the question

Comment: @cid It was downvoted, because we shouldn't answer trivial duplicates.